# Differences between default GET behaviour of `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch`?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

Are there any differences between the `XHRGet` and `FetchGet` functions below in terms of the final request that gets sent to the server of `url`? Do they have different default headers, or anything like that? While using both methods for web crawling I've noticed that `fetch` tends to fail more often than `XMLHttpRequest`, and I'm not sure why that is the case.

```
(async () => {
  console.log( await XHRGet("https://stackoverflow.com") );
  console.log( await fetchGet("https://stackoverflow.com") );
})();

function XHRGet(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.addEventListener("load", function() { resolve(this.responseText); });
    req.open("GET", url);
    req.send();
  });
}

function fetchGet(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(res => res.text());
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch()` doesn't include credentials by default. I'm looking to change that in https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/pull/585. After that these should be nearly identical. (There's also some decoding differences. `fetch()` will always use UTF-8. `XMLHttpRequest` is a bit more lenient. That should not result in failure though, just possibly different result strings.)